# ListView.addFooterView() not working if no items in listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am adding footer to listview using,

```
View footerview = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_social, null, false);            
listview_followers.addFooterView(footerview);
```

Here is my listview in xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_followers"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

And footerview xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend_social"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/botao_bgg"
        android:text="SEND"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

footerview.xml successfully added if there are items in listview. If there are no items in listview, footerview is also not displayed.

Can anybody help about this?

Comment: A suggestion:you can create a separate layout for listview and include  the footer in the listview xml file.Then I am sure that your footer will be shown even the listview is empty.

Comment: @kgandroid Yeh but main.xml + footerview.xml have lots of content so i have applied setOnTouchListener to listview so that it will scroll with listview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think that its possible to add a footer to an empty `ListView`. Though `ListView` can use an empty `View` which can is displayed when there are no items in the `ListView`. now there are 2 ways to do this:

### 1:

```
RelativeLayout empty = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
           R.layout.empty_view,
           null);
((ViewGroup)list.getParent()).addView(empty);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### 2:

```
RelativeLayout empty = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
           R.layout.empty_view,
           (ViewGroup) list.getParent());
list.setEmptyView(empty);
```

here `empty` is of type `View` so it can be a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` which can be inflated using `LayoutInflater` during runtime.

**NOTE:** make sure you set the adapter after adding the empty view.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its not working mate,listview_followers.setEmptyView(footerview);

Comment: View footerview = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
    .inflate(R.layout.footer_social, null, false);

Comment: @Prince make sure to inflate `footerView` before inflating `ListView`

Comment: Sorry but not getting you.

Comment: Working like a charm :D :D